# Profile tabs are not working

Tags: php, html

I have 3 tabs on a profile-page: About, Messages and Newsfeed. The newsfeed working correctly but when i click on about or messages it stays on the newsfeed tab even though it shows   http://localhost/demo/pan_peter_1#messages_div

I can't figure out why...

[image: picture of tabs]

```
<div class="profile_main_column column">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="profileTabs">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#about_div" aria-controls="about_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages_div" aria-controls="messages_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#newsfeed_div" aria-controls="newsfeed_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Newsfeed</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="about_div">
            <?php echo $info; ?>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="newsfeed_div">
            <div class="posts_area"></div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="messages_div">
            <?php
                echo "<h4>You and <a href='" . $username ."'>" . $profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "</a></h4><hr><br>";

                echo "<div class='loaded_messages' id='scroll_messages'>";
                echo $message_obj->getMessages($username);
                echo "</div>";
            ?>

            <div class="message_post">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <textarea name='message_body' id='message_textarea' placeholder='Write your message ...'></textarea>
                    <input type='submit' name='post_message' class='info' id='message_submit' value='Send'>
                </form>
            </div>

            <script>
                var div = document.getElementById("scroll_messages");
                div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us your JS file?